# Sid Meier's Civilization V Crashes on multiplayer (Internet)

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-5

Ok, I'll get to the point: about a week ago, Civ stopped working on internet multiplayer (I have not tested lan connection). Singleplayer works fine. But when I get invited to a game to play with my one of my friends, it will be on the normal multiplayer menu with the nation list and server info, and then after a while (sometimes when the game is started and you have your opening dialogue about your nation, sometimes even before the game is started) it will crash. I took the liberty of creating a paste on pastebin out of the crash log: http://pastebin.com/71zZ5wLS Any help would be appreciated :)

To clarify, he game we are using is a PREVIOUSLY existing game that we have played on before and experienced no technical issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just started a new game. Save data was likely corrupted on the previous one.